# CSS sub menu positioning off in everything except Firefox

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I've had this trouble before with pure CSS sub menus. It looks fine in FF (On OS X at least) but in other browsers it's aligned with the right hand side of the parent li as oppose to the left as it should be.

An example can be seem below (Hover over "About us" or "My Landmark 24")

[removed URL]

Does anyone have any idea what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to try isolate the problem into a seperate code and post it, for example, on jsfiddle.net - otherwise future users won't be able to get what the problem discusses was

Comment: have you tried adding top and left to the submenu css?

Comment: Could you please test if left: 0; in `.navigation ul.menu li ul.sub-menu` helps u out?

Comment: I've removed the URL from my question now and I'll upload a sample of code to jsfiddle now so it might help someone out in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to your `.navigation ul.menu li ul.sub-menu` css class style `left:0px`.

Comment: BOOM!! Worked a treat. I should have thought of that myself. Thank you

Comment: both answered the same thing at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

on the `.navigation ul.menu li ul.sub-menu {` just add `left:0;` that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your submenu is set to `display:inline` on hover. If you change that to `display:block` it should be fixed.

```
.navigation ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```